# ! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal

Tags: math-mode, packages

I have a problem to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\input{../Master/header}
\input{../Master/commands.tex}
%======================================================
\begin{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

I tried to make use of package

```
 \usepackage{bm}
```

as suggested by several people to fix the issue but this even provides me with more errors.

I also know that some nice packages like

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

can be helpful to avoid such errors but its too late for me to restructure my long file to use this package.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Which math fonts are loaded in the files `header.tex` and `command.tex`?

Comment: bm (more or less) doubles the the number of font families needed so makes this error more rather than less likely but without any relevant code posted it's impossible to suggest what you should change. please make a self contained example that allows people to reproduce the error.

Comment: so many times i faced this problem!!!!!!!!!